# Insert into a new Table in SQL gives error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Why am I getting an error?

```
--Q1    

CREATE table  Aorders (
 Id  INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
 CreatedDate Date NOT NULL,
 BillingCountry varchar Not Null,
 MerchId int Not null,
 OrderStatus varchar Not null,
);

--Q2    

select * from Aorders

--Q3 edited as suggested here but still get an error
```

INSERT INTO Aorders (CreatedDate, BillingCountry, MerchId, OrderStatus)
VALUES  ('2001-01-01', 'Israel', 5 ,'Approved');

Comment: The date format you are using for the column CreatedDate is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the length of the varchar columns like:

```
CREATE table  Aorders (
 Id  INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
 CreatedDate Date NOT NULL,
 BillingCountry varchar(100) Not Null,
 MerchId int Not null,
 OrderStatus varchar(100) Not null,
);
```

From [char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> When n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1

Answer (score 1):

When doing an `insert`, the best practice is to list all the columns explicitly and to use standard formats for dates:

```
INSERT INTO Aorders (CreatedDate, BillingCountry, MerchId, OrderStatus)
    VALUES ('2001-01-01', 'Israel', 5 ,'Approved');
```

Your specific error is because you have four values in the `VALUES()` list but there are five columns in the table.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, You forgot to include CreatedDate column. I did that on your behalf. Since first column is identity, So there is no need to include that column in INSERT query.

Comment: tried..
 INSERT INTO Aorders (CreatedDate, BillingCountry, MerchId, OrderStatus)
VALUES  ('01.01.01', 'Israel', 5 ,'Approved');

still getting the same error...

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 12
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Completion time: 2019-08-03T18:57:55.7867677+03:00

Comment: @pnetaly, See the difference between Gordon's Date format and yours

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i tried with '2001-01-01' , still same error :(

Comment: Which DBMS product you are using?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai  Microsoft SQL Server Management studio

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 21
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Completion time: 2019-08-03T19:13:36.6518616+03:00

Comment: Please mention the size when using VARCHAR datatype. If you will not mention size, It will assign by default it as only 1. You are trying to insert Israel but size is only 1. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have not done your query properly. I think you want the ID to auto increment ,but you haven't declare that. Make changes as below:

```
CREATE table Aorders ( Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
                      ,CreatedDate Date NOT NULL
                      ,BillingCountry varchar Not Null
                      ,MerchId int Not null
                      ,OrderStatus varchar Not null);
```

Now enter the query as you have inserted. And also make sure proper date formats from documentation.